# Non-Registry Fix for Secondary Mailboxes Sent Items

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2007

There is a known issue with Outlook and Exchange where "secondary" mailboxes which are mounted in the same profile, e.g. "John Doe" + CorpMailbox1, CorpMailbox2, CorpMailbox3 will place "sent items" from the secondary mailboxes (e.g. CorpMailbox1) in the user's (e.g. "John Doe") Sent Items folder.

There is a registry value (something like `DelegateSentItems`) to semi-fix this, but I'm looking for an Exchange-side solution.

It seems like, at some point, an admin made CC rules to fix this, and for the mailboxes where I see a BCC rule: any item sent to [address] BCC to [address].

The behavior "fixes" the issue, but when I duplicate this work-around for new shared mailboxes, the email ends up in the Inbox and not the Sent Items for the shared mailbox.

I don't believe there is any outlook/client-side shenanigans going on, as the intended behavior for the older mailboxes works for new PCs/Users (new imagse) without any Outlook Mailbox Rules.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there are rules for each mailbox that grabs the mail and moves it from the sent items folder. One must just not tell it to use the rule "for this machine only".

I suppose, in a sense, it's an exchange-side rule, though you'd have to mount the mailbox and set the rule up.